# Selecting logged in username, showing their data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to SQL/asp.net/VB. I'm attempting to create an account history page. I need the query to use their Username and pull data from two different tables. The query only selects a distinct input.

```
SELECT Payment.PAID_ID, Payment.PAY_RECEIVED, Payment.PAYMENT_DATE, 
Payment.PAYMENT_SUMMARY, Payment.USER_NAME, Schedule.SCHEDULE_ID, 
Schedule.SERVICE_DATE, Schedule.SERVICETIME_IN, 
              Schedule.SERVICETIME_OUT, Schedule.EMAIL, Schedule.ADDRESS, 
Schedule.FIRST_NAME, Schedule.LAST_NAME, Schedule.USER_NAME
FROM     Payment CROSS JOIN
              Schedule
WHERE  (Payment.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
```

This query gets all the correct information but, it needs an input to get the correct information to display on the data table. Is there a way to determine the Username on the .aspx page?

UPDATE: I changed my query to this.

```
SELECT Payment.PAY_RECEIVED, Payment.PAYMENT_DATE, Payment.PAYMENT_SUMMARY, 
Payment.USER_NAME, Schedule.SCHEDULE_ID, Schedule.SERVICE_DATE, 
Schedule.EMAIL, Schedule.ADDRESS, Schedule.FIRST_NAME, 
              Schedule.LAST_NAME, Schedule.USER_NAME AS Expr1
FROM     Payment INNER JOIN
              Schedule ON Payment.USER_NAME = Schedule.USER_NAME
WHERE  (Payment.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
```

I set my session variable to

```
Session("roles")
```

How do I get the object data source to read the session? [image: image of objectdatasource parameters]

Comment: How do users "login" to your aspx site?

Comment: To find user name are you in a work network?  Or if you have your own login there may be a custom variable/object to hold the user data/id

Comment: How can this possibly show the correct info when the `Schedule` table is not limited by User? You're gonna end up with a cartesian product showing every user's schedule data. Somehow the Payment and Schedule data need to be related to each other.

Comment: @Tab Alleman They use the login wizard. They have to create a username, get verified via email, and then they can login.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Could you explain more? Because in the query builder it gives me the correct information i need.

Comment: Ok I don't know what the login wizard does.. does it use Active Directory, or does it create entries in a User table?

Comment: CROSS JOIN will combine every included payment record with every possible Schedule record. You'll see the right payments because you also limit that in the WHERE clause, but there is nothing in that query to limit Schedules. It might show the right data if your sample data only has schedules for one user. Otherwise, I would double check this. You probably want an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN here. CROSS JOIN is **very rare** in real-world use.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Okay that makes sense. Would using the UNION be a better option for this?

Comment: If you can modify the login form, if you have access to code behind of login form, then you might want to use a `Session["whatever"]` object which act like a global var, except that the variable will disappear when session ends. I use that a lot. Once you have stored the user login name in this object, you can retrieve it anywhere until his session ends for some reasons.

Comment: @TabAlleman It creates entries in a User table

Comment: In that case, your site needs to keep track of the current user in a session variable or something similar that persists from page to page.   Does it?

Comment: @TabAlleman it keeps track of the session. A user has access to different pages than an Admin.

Comment: Ok, then the session is where you'd find the username to plug into your SQL statement.   There's nothing built in by default for this, it's all dependent on the way your site is programmed.

Comment: Look up table aliases as well. It makes the code easier to read

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776348/8890574 Moved over to another thread where my answer is posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem with user name has been well answered in comments. With regards to your SQL, no, you do not want Union. Try an inner join and see if that gets the data you need.

```
FROM Payment INNER JOIN
    Schedule ON Payment.USERNAME = Schedule.USER_NAME
WHERE (Payment.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks! that seems to be a better way to do that. I'm still having trouble displaying this query in a gridview

Comment: I think a new question where you include your code where you attempt to display in datagrid and explain any errors you get and what happens that is different from what you expect.