# Bind User.Identity.Name to a gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

New to ASP.NET and SQL. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to bind User.Identity.Name to a gridview.

When I use the query tester, I get the correct data but when I run aspx page the Gridview doesn't show up at all.

```
SELECT Payment.PAY_RECEIVED, Payment.PAYMENT_DATE, Payment.PAYMENT_SUMMARY, 
Payment.USER_NAME, Schedule.SCHEDULE_ID, Schedule.SERVICE_DATE, 
Schedule.EMAIL, Schedule.ADDRESS, Schedule.FIRST_NAME, 
              Schedule.LAST_NAME, Schedule.USER_NAME AS Expr1
FROM     Payment INNER JOIN
              Schedule ON Payment.USER_NAME = Schedule.USER_NAME
WHERE  (Payment.USER_NAME = @USER_NAME)
```

VB code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="PAID_ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAID_ID" HeaderText="PAID_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PAID_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAY_RECEIVED" HeaderText="PAY_RECEIVED" SortExpression="PAY_RECEIVED" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAYMENT_DATE" HeaderText="PAYMENT_DATE" SortExpression="PAYMENT_DATE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAYMENT_SUMMARY" HeaderText="PAYMENT_SUMMARY" SortExpression="PAYMENT_SUMMARY" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="USER_NAME" HeaderText="USER_NAME" SortExpression="USER_NAME" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetDataByCustomer" TypeName="DataSetTableAdapters.PaymentTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Original_PAID_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PAY_RECEIVED" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PAYMENT_DATE" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PAYMENT_SUMMARY" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="USER_NAME" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ProfileParameter DefaultValue="e.InputParamater[&quot;USER_NAME&quot;] = HttpContext.Current.User.Name" Name="USER_NAME" PropertyName="USER_NAME" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

How do I get the object data source to read the User.Identity.Name?

Comment: How is VBA relevant to this question? Did you mean VB.NET?

Comment: Also, ...where's the VB code? Obviously if you run this query and you get the correct data then the problem isn't with the query.. see [mcve]

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sorry, I forgot to add the VB code and tagged the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution. First I switched the to a SQL from object datasource.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Schedule] WHERE ([USER_NAME] = @USER_NAME)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="USER_NAME" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Went into the aspx.vb page and put this and it worked like a charm

```
    Private Sub SqlDataSource2_Selecting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource2.Selecting
    e.Command.Parameters("@USER_NAME").Value = User.Identity.Name
End Sub
```